# Refer to renamed columns in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT name, gdp/population as capita 
FROM world w1 
WHERE continent = 'Europe'      
AND capita > 
(
    SELECT gdp/population 
    FROM world 
    WHERE name = 'United Kingdom'
);
```

How come I can't refer to `capita` in the `WHERE` clause? It returns this error:

```
Unknown column 'capita' in 'where clause'
```

I can however, run the query if I replace `capita` with `gdp/population`.

I don't want to do `gdp/population > ...`. How can I do `capita > ...`? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a View in your database

```
USE mydb;
CREATE VIEW name_capita AS
SELECT name, gdp/population as capita,continent FROM world;
```

Then, apply the `WHERE` clause to the View

```
USE mydb;
SELECT * FROM name_capita
WHERE continent = 'Europe' AND
capita > (SELECT gdp/population FROM world WHERE name = 'United Kingdom');
```

or even re-using the view:

```
SELECT * FROM name_capita
WHERE continent = 'Europe' AND
capita > (SELECT capita FROM name_capita WHERE name = 'United Kingdom');
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Nice. Then you could use the view in the subquery as well: `AND capita > (SELECT capita FROM name_capita WHERE name = 'United Kingdom');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use column alias in Order BY Only, not in Where Clause.

Try following

```
;With CTE as (
SELECT name, gdp/population as capita 
FROM world
)

SELECT * FROM CTE Where capita > 
(
    SELECT gdp/population 
    FROM world 
    WHERE name = 'United Kingdom'
);
```